# Phonegap GPS without internet

Tags: geolocation, gps, cordova

I m trying to make an android app which  count the distance traveled from
log,lan values with phonegap.But phonegap GPS work only  when internet or wifi in
ON  condition.How can get log ,lan values without internet by using
geolocation api.Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 22):

See the PhoneGap API Docs for [Geolocation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocationOptions) under the geoLocationOptions:

> **Android Quirks**
>
> The Android 2.x simulators will not return a geolocation result unless the     enableHighAccuracy option is set to true.
>
> ```
> { enableHighAccuracy: true }
> ```

Enabling that option will allow the Android device to get the location even with the WIFI option disabled.

Comment: I know its old, but I can't make it work on my Galaxy S3. I can't get the corect location because the gps icon doesn't show when I set this parameter to true.